# Does QuickBlox support push messages with content-available flag for iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

I couldn't find this parameter in APNS options. Please add this functionality to admin console. For reference, description from your competitor:

> content-available: (iOS only) If you are a writing a Newsstand app, or an app using the >Remote Notification Background Mode introduced in iOS7 (a.k.a. "Background Push"), set this >value to 1 to trigger a background download.

Thank in advance, although that option is missing, your servise is awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is under development, as I know it will be released in 1-2 weeks.

So, stay tuned with quickblox blog http://quickblox.com/blog/

It will available in Admin panel and through API as well

**UPDATE**

QuickBlox rolled out this update, check this feature in https://admin.quickblox.com